# What size should i apply for favicon?

Tags: favicon, sizing

I have sized a favicon with 20px and 5px. but it's showing stretched and not looking well at all. what should I do to set favicon nicely on my project? Here's my project link.

https://github.com/Ferdousnayeem/ninja-mail

Comment: Your image itself is not proper. I would suggest keeping some icon rather than text in the image.

Answer (score 0):

The optimal size for the favicon without it getting stretched would be `16x16`

Answer (score 0):

At least 64x64 for reasonable appearance,